# Chrome 69 image inside iframe bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have structure like

```
<iframe>
  <script>
  </script>
  <iframe>
    <a href='..'>
      <img src=".." />
    </a>
  </iframe>
</iframe>
```

If I scroll page down and then returns .. the image view vanished.

Any know how to fix this?

Comment: Please see [ask]. We can only help you if you could create a [mcve]. You can [edit] your question, and create a snippet using the code button `[<>]` in editor.

Comment: Are you even allowed to put iframe in iframes....that seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

yep, chrome 69 does that, Add style="transform:translateZ(0)" to your image it will solve the problem. (if you have control on the iframe of course)
If you don't have control on the iframe, you can put the style on the iframe level., it will also solve the issue.

Remark: the bug is solved on chrome 70